# Laravel 7 Socialite Google Login Shows Invalid Grant Error

Tags: laravel, google-signin, laravel-socialite, laravel-7

I have used the Socialite library for google login.

When trying to fetch the user data after successful google login it shows an invalid grant message

```
$googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
```

Response

```
Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
    {
      "error": "invalid_grant",
      "error_description": "Bad Request"
    }
```

The same code working on my local machine and previous laravel versions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: same issue. any solusion have you found? or any one if possibly could help

Comment: @atiehmokhtary Hi, look at my aolution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and following code helped me:

```
$googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')
->with(['access_type' => 'offline'])
->user();
```

[Here's more about this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/socialite